# Weclient does not refresh sending followed requested

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using php script to get the data out of mysql database on my server. Doing a web client request to get the data.

```
mywebsite.com/get_serials_notused.php
```

like this, then taking out data in a string and using it.

the problem I facing is that when I send two conversative requested with interval of few seconds. it does not refresh the data. shows me the existing data only. possibly it is sending a new request but not getting the latest data.

I am using VB.net and Code is

```
wc = New WebClient
str1 = wc.DownloadString("mywebsite.com/get_serials_notused.php")
```